# Changing http.sys settings in Win 2012 server

Tags: iis, windows-server-2012

My understanding is that if I want to tweak settings like `MaxRequestBytes` that I have to go to the [registry](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/820129)-- specifically, in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\HTTP\Parameters`

In my registry however, there are no such keys under that path. Is it the case only customizations to those keys go under there, and the default values are hard-coded?  Or is this information not stored in the registry for Win 2012 server and is instead elsewhere?

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can tell, these values do not exist in the registry by default. I assume you're correct in that they are hardcoded, but would be overridden if you add them.

Http.sys registry settings for Windows
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/820129

I know that points to Windows Server 2003, but I have not been able to find an updated version for Windows Server 2012 so I'm working on the assumption this is still accurate.

UPDATE (11/21/2019)
It looks like the support article was updated since I first replied and now shows Windows Server 2003 through Windows 2012 R2, as well as Windows 7 and Windows 8.